How to create a new table containing all unique strings extracted from JSON arrays in the column of another table. SQL
I have table describing music and column genres contains values like ["genre1", "genre2","genre3",..] (multiple genres can belong to one song).
I need to create table describing each genre based on my table describing popularity of music and I struggle with extracting these values
Music



name
genres
popularity




Track1
[genre1,genre2]
45.545


Trakc2
[genre3,genre4]
34.554



I need:
Genres



Genre
AVG_Popularity




genre1
popularity1


genre2
popularity1



I'm new to SQL so didn't come up with an idea worth showing here
That's what I get with help of GPT (doesn't work):
INSERT INTO distinct_genres (genre)
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(genres, CONCAT('$[', numbers.n, ']'))) AS genre
FROM top_50_2023
JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
) numbers
WHERE JSON_LENGTH(genres) > numbers.n;


Use JSON_TABLE()
